# Clone table row limited up to two rows?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to dynamically add another row to my table but its only adding one row and wont add anymore.

Here is the html:

```
<table class="pretty property_units" style="width:800px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Bedroom</th>
<th>Bathroom</th>
<th>Square Feet</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Available</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="rows">
    <td><input type='text' name='bedroom[]' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='bath[]' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='sqrt[]' class='input-small'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='price[]' class='input-small'></td>
    <td>
        <select name='avail[]' class='input-small'>
        <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
        <option value='no'>No</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-small'>remove</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tblrow = $('table.property_units tr.rows:first-child').clone();
    $(".addrow").click(function() {
    $("table.property_units").append(tblrow);
    });
});
</script>
```

Notice how I'm not writing out the table row in append? I don't want to write it out, so please don't add that as a solution. It makes the code very messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the row to the table, but you should be appending it to the `<tbody>`:

```
$("table.property_units tbody").append(tblrow);
```

Also, `:first-child` is an invalid selector. You meant to use `:first`:

```
$('table.property_units tr.rows:first').clone();
```

Also, move the clone INTO the click function:

```
$(".addrow").click(function() {
    var tblrow = $('table.property_units tr.rows:first').clone();
    $("table.property_units tbody").append(tblrow);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ygGt/4/

Comment: thanks for your post, i've tried it with tbody and it didnt work in the past. But i tried what you mentioned and it wont add anymore than 1. I looked in firebug and it doesnt report any problems.

Comment: nice thanks that worked. I looked into firebug before your new update and noticed when i tried to add a row it was overwriting the last row given and wasnt appending anything new. The tr row was highlighting. But what you mentioned worked, should've thought of that lol. Thanks for your help :)